# Angular Google Maps/NodeJS: Display Markers from Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, google-maps

I'm building an application with NodeJS and Angular Google Maps to display a set of data/coordinates from MongoDB onto the map. However, I'm unable to get the data and display it. How would I correct the code to make it work? Below is my code:

View

```
<ui-gmap-google-map 
    center='map.center' 
    zoom='map.zoom'>

  <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="marker in markers"
      coords="'marker.latitude' + 'marker.longitude'" 
      options="marker.options" 
      events="marker.events" 
      idkey="marker.id">
    <ui-gmap-window>
       <div>{{marker.window.name}}</div>
    </ui-gmap-window>
  </ui-gmap-marker>
 </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JSON Data from API

```
[{"_id":"5686389d2959b4c601fbd9e7","longitude":120.93313390000003,"latitude":14.5571256,"location":"Hotel Intercontinental Manila","category":"Accomodation","name":"Hotel Intercon Manila","__v":0,"reviews":[]},     
  {"_id":"56873fdb182b3741059357d1","longitude":123.76338959999998,"latitude":10.2594266,"location":"Cebu City","name":"Cebu City","__v":0,"reviews":[{"comment":"This is a test","rating":null,"userId":null,"review_id":"tiGCG2rGroIn"}]},
{"_id":"5687245aecdf89fb033b18b3","longitude":121.0212325,"latitude":14.5896977,"location":"Mandaluyong, Manila","category":"Accomodation","name":"Mandaluyong","__v":0,"reviews":[]}]
```

Controller

```
 .controller('MapCtrl', function($state, $scope, LocFac) {  
   var Markers =  LocFac.getLocations().then(function(data) { 
      return data.data; 
   }); 

   $scope.map = { 
      center: { latitude: 14.8282, longitude: 122.5795 }, 
      zoom: 1 
   };

   $scope.markers = Markers;

 })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an example](https://plnkr.co/edit/AjNZGysuZCbSyYk9pUv8?p=preview) of how displaying markers on the map works. A couple of pointers:

- When displaying multiple markers, use the `ui-gmap-markers` directive instead of `ng-repeat`ing the single marker directive.
- Similarly, use the plural version `ui-gmap-windows` to show the windows.
- The markers directive reads the coordinates from an object key you provide to it: `<ui-gmap-markers coords="'coords'" ... >` reads the coordinates from the `coords` attribute of your marker. Same goes for other attributes, too, like `events`, `options` etc.
- I assume your `LocFac.getLocations()` returns a promise - thus your `Markers` variable very likely isn't getting assigned correctly. You're better off assigning `$scope.markers` inside the `.then` callback of your API call as follows:

  ```
  $scope.markers = []; // init markers to empty array so angular-google-maps has something to draw markers from
  LocFac.getLocations().then(function(data) {
      var markers = data.data;
      angular.forEach(markers, function(marker) {
          // Assign 'coords' attribute here for the directive to read
          marker.coords = {
              latitude: marker.latitude,
              longitude: marker.longitude
          }
      })
      $scope.markers = markers;
  }
  ```

If you still need help after this, I'll be happy to provide some :)