# Is it possible to place Google Map Markers on Node.js and than pass to Angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mean-stack

I've been trying to figure out if it's anyway possible to render google maps on the server side - like placing markers on the map from MongoDB and than pass the rendered map onto the client to display it along with all of the markers?

Basically I would like to display a map with a lot of markers on the client but do not wish to create them on the client side. Ideally, the client receives rendered map and displays it, any additional information is than sent back to server to add append to the map. Is this possible?

I looked into FusionTables and KML and also  https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps but not sure if it's possible to just render on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a backend hit to get the markers, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34689682/3337164) answer can help you:

Bharat.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) may be a solution for you. The rendering is done server side by Google maps. It's not done on your server but it's also not client side.

The node googlemaps package you referenced will allow you to do the request server side: [googlemaps - Static Maps](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps#static-maps)